# Pygame change particle color

Tags: python, pygame

So I have this piece of code:

```py
import pygame

def colors():
    import random
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    pygame.init()
    pygame.font.init
    pygame.display.set_caption('Colors')
    SCREEN = width, height = 900,600
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN,0,32)
    particles = []
    running = True
    click = False
    while running:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))
        button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
        button_1.centerx = width/2
        color = (255,255,255)
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (135, 206, 235), button_1)
        text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, 'Particle:', (255,255,255), (100), (300), False)
        color_t = 'White'
        font = pygame.font.Font('pixel.ttf', 30)



        text = font.render(color_t, True, color) 

        textRect = text.get_rect()  

        textRect.center = ((180), (300))


        screen.blit(text, textRect)
        text_speech('pixel.ttf', 50, 'Colors', (255,255,255), (button_1.centerx), (button_1.centery), False)
        particles.append([[150,200],[random.randint(0,20) / 10 - 1, 1], random.randint(4,6)])
        for particle in particles:
            particle[0][0] += particle[1][0]
            particle[0][1] += particle[1][1]
            particle[2] -= 0.1
            particle[1][1] += 0.03
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, [int(particle[0][0]), int(particle[0][1])], int(particle[2]))
            if particle[2] <= 0:
                particles.remove(particle)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            if event.type == MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1:
                    click = True
        mx, my = pygame.mouse.get_pos()

        if textRect.collidepoint((mx,my)):
            if click:
                color_t = 'Red'
                color = (255,0,0)
                text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, (180), (300), False)
        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

def text_speech(font : str ,size : int,text : str,color,x,y, bold : bool):
    SCREEN = width, height = 900, 600
    font = pygame.font.Font(font,size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    text = font.render(text, True, color)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (x,y)
    screen.blit(text,textRect)
colors()
```

[and it produces this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/znwZJ.png)
[[image]

If I click on the text, the word 'Red' just overlaps the word 'White' and the circle colour doesn't change. I was wondering how to make it so that if the user clicks on the text, it replaces the previous word (in this case White) with the new word( red) and also changes the colour of the circle

Comment: You could try to fill the background with the color black after you click the text and before you blit the new text. That way the original text and circle are removed so they don't overlap.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Create a function, which renders the text, but doesn't `blit` it to the window surface:

```py
def render_text_speech(fontname, size, text, color, x, y, bold):
    SCREEN = width, height = 900, 600
    font = pygame.font.Font(fontname, size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    text = font.render(text, True, color)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (x,y)
    return text, textRect
```

Render the text before the main application loop and `blit` the text surfaces continuously to the window surface in the loop:

```py
def colors():
    # [...]

    button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
    button_1.centerx = width/2
    color = (255,255,255)
    color_t = 'White'
    text_particle = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, 'Particle:', (255,255,255), 100, 300, False)
    text_colors = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 50, 'Colors', (255,255,255), button_1.centerx, button_1.centery, False)
    text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)

    # [...]
    while running:
        # [...]

        screen.blit(*text_particle)
        screen.blit(*text_colors)
        screen.blit(*text_color)
```

It is sufficient to re-render the text surface when the text mouse button is pressed:

```py
def colors():
    # [...]

    while running:
        # [...]

        for event in pygame.event.get():
            # [...]

            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1 and textRect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    color_t = 'Red'
                    color = (255,0,0)
                    text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)
```

---

See the example:

[image]

```py
import pygame
import random

pygame.init()
pygame.font.init()
pygame.display.set_caption('Colors')
SCREEN = width, height = 900,600
screen = pygame.display.set_mode(SCREEN,0,32)

def render_text_speech(fontname, size, text, color, x, y, bold):
    SCREEN = width, height = 900, 600
    font = pygame.font.SysFont(None, size)
    #font = pygame.font.Font(fontname, size)
    font.set_bold(bold)
    text = font.render(text, True, color)
    textRect = text.get_rect()
    textRect.center = (x,y)
    return text, textRect

def colors():
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()

    button_1 = pygame.Rect(width/2, (height/10), width/4, 60)
    button_1.centerx = width/2
    colors = [("White", (255, 255, 255)), ("Red", (255, 0, 0)), ("Green", (0, 255, 0)), ("Blue", (0, 0, 255))]
    current_color = 0
    color_t, color = colors[current_color]
    text_particle = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, 'Particle:', (255,255,255), 100, 300, False)
    text_colors = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 50, 'Colors', (255,255,255), button_1.centerx, button_1.centery, False)
    text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)

    particles = []
    running = True
    while running:
        screen.fill((0,0,0))

        pygame.draw.rect(screen, (135, 206, 235), button_1)
        screen.blit(*text_particle)
        screen.blit(*text_colors)
        screen.blit(*text_color)
        textRect = text_color[1]

        particles.append([[150,200],[random.randint(0,20) / 10 - 1, 1], random.randint(4,6)])
        for particle in particles:
            particle[0][0] += particle[1][0]
            particle[0][1] += particle[1][1]
            particle[2] -= 0.1
            particle[1][1] += 0.03
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, color, [int(particle[0][0]), int(particle[0][1])], int(particle[2]))
            if particle[2] <= 0:
                particles.remove(particle)
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                pygame.quit()
                sys.exit()
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_ESCAPE:
                    running = False
            if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
                if event.button == 1 and textRect.collidepoint(event.pos):
                    current_color += 1
                    if current_color >= len(colors):
                        current_color = 0
                    color_t, color = colors[current_color]
                    text_color = render_text_speech('pixel.ttf', 30, color_t, color, 180, 300, False)

        pygame.display.update()
        clock.tick(60)

colors()
```

Comment: Is it possible to do this with multiple colors?. Like after clicking red, can there be another option?

Comment: @waild Yes it is. Just set the `color_t` and `color` from a list.

Comment: Do you mean make a list of color names as well as color codes in a list?

Comment: @walid I've change the example in the answer.

Comment: Thanks, this was extremely helpful!